# How to output Taxonomy Tabs in Views (without URL only #hashtag)?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

i want to output a Bootstrap Tab and the Tabs are my Taxonomy Terms of "Meal Category".

I had install the Module "views_bootstrap" and it work without any problems but i can't add a summary for the terms.

If i remove the filter for the terms in conditional filter option i get a tab for each content.. so i get more tabs that i want :(

So my main problem is to filter the term name to one.. and each term in my tab navigation has to output all results.. Currently i get for each content a tab and each tab in my navigation output only one content.

Anybody has a solution?

Comment: I don't understand what your end goal is. Can you attach a picture/diagram of what you are trying to accomplish?